# How to read an OpenAPI JSON file from a URL in C# using Swashbuckle?

Tags: c#, openapi, swashbuckle

I'd like to read an OpenAPI definition from a URL in C# (I'm using .NET Core 3.1).  Example definition:

```json
{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    "title": "ExampleAPI",
    "version": "v1"
  },
  "paths": {
    "/WeatherForecast": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "WeatherForecast"
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Success",
            "content": {
              "text/plain": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "array",
                  "items": {
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/WeatherForecast"
                  }
                }
              },
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "array",
                  "items": {
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/WeatherForecast"
                  }
                }
              },
              "text/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "array",
                  "items": {
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/WeatherForecast"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "WeatherForecast": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "date": {
            "type": "string",
            "format": "date-time"
          },
          "temperatureC": {
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int32"
          },
          "temperatureF": {
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int32",
            "readOnly": true
          },
          "summary": {
            "type": "string",
            "nullable": true
          }
        },
        "additionalProperties": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to have a `SwaggerDocument` that I can parse and read all controller methods, the parameterss for those methods, the models in the response, etc.

I don't have a code sample, I'm really struggling to find any examples of this. Has anyone done something similar? Or have any pointers?

Comment: I think Swashbuckle can only generate OpenAPI files, not read them. Check out https://github.com/microsoft/OpenAPI.NET instead.

Comment: Thanks @Helen!  That was exactly what I needed! It does it perfectly!